# How can I join two dataframes based on matching values in one column?

Tags: python, pandas

I start with two dataframes:

```
              Breakfast        Lunch
1  Monday     Cereal           Sandwich
2  Wednesday  Eggs             Salad
```

```
              Dinner           Snack
1  Monday     Ham              Chips
2  Tuesday    Pasta            Nuts
3  Wednesday  Chicken          Apple
```

How can I join these two dataframes comparing weekdays in to something like:

```
              Breakfast        Lunch        Dinner           Snack
1  Monday     Cereal           Sandwich     Ham              Chips
2  Tuesday                                  Pasta            Nuts
3  Wednesday  Eggs             Salad        Chicken          Apple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `join` (to take advantage of the fact that you're merging on index); then `groupby` index level 1 (which are days of the week) and use `first` (which by default drops NaN values)

```
out = df1.join(df2, how='outer').groupby(level=1).first().replace({None:''})
```

Output:

```
          Breakfast     Lunch   Dinner  Snack
Monday       Cereal  Sandwich      Ham  Chips
Tuesday                          Pasta   Nuts
Wednesday      Eggs     Salad  Chicken  Apple
```